# unique ID creation for each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

**Overview**: There is an array of `product group` object and each product group having array of `items`. Product group object having unique ID but items array does not have any unique ID assigned. Please find below the JSON object.

```
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}, {
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}];
```

**Requirement :** Assign some unique ID for each items object of `items` array based on the product group.

**I tried so far :** [working solution : concat index of product group with the index of each list items](https://jsfiddle.net/h84wLqz9/)

```js
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}, {
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}];

const itemList = productList.map(obj => {
    obj.items.map((itemObj, index) => {
    itemObj.productGroup = obj.productGroup;
    itemObj.pgIndex = obj.index;
    itemObj.itemIndex = obj.index + '' + index;
  });
  return obj.items;
});

var mergedListItems = itemList.reduce((arr, arrNext) => arr.concat(arrNext));

console.log('mergedListItems', mergedListItems);
```

Is this approach good? If not, then what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What is the product group unique `id`, the `index` or the `productGroup` key?

Comment: @Shidersz index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might `.reduce` into the output array immediately, rather than iterating over the items multiple times:

```js
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}, {
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}];

const mergedListItems = productList.reduce((a, { productGroup, index, items }) => {
  items.forEach((itemObj, itemIndex) => {
    a.push({
      ...itemObj,
      productGroup,
      pgIndex: index,
      itemIndex: `${index}${itemIndex}`
    });
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(mergedListItems);
```

Also note that there's a potential problem with your

```
itemObj.itemIndex = obj.index + '' + index;
```

logic - what if either `index` is greater than 10? Then, you might see an item with an `itemIndex` of, for example, `111`. What does that mean, does it mean that the original object's index was 11, or was the item index 11? If possible, consider putting an underscore or some separator between them, for example

```
itemObj.itemIndex = obj.index + '_' + index;
```

Or, using the template literal like in my code

```
itemIndex: `${index}_${itemIndex}`
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use

```
itemObj.itemIndex = obj.index + '' + index;
```

Which can be not unique for case like `obj.index=12 index=3` and `obj.index=1 index=23`. But if you change `''` to `'-'` it will be unique.

Try to add field 'id' to each items object as follows `id= productGroup.index + '-' + i` (where i is item index in array)

```
productList.forEach(pr=>pr.items.forEach((x,i)=> x.id = pr.index+'-'+i ));
```

```js
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}, {
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}];

productList.forEach(pr=>pr.items.forEach((x,i)=> x.id = pr.index+'-'+i ));

console.log(productList);
```

You can also create uniqe id independent of productGroup.index

```
let i=0;
productList.forEach(pr=>pr.items.forEach(x=> x.id = i++ ));
```

```js
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}, {
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  },{
    item1: 'item1 value',
    item2: 'item2 value'
  }]
}];

let i=0;
productList.forEach(pr=>pr.items.forEach(x=> x.id = i++ ));

console.log(productList);
```

Comment: Thanks. May i know which one is better to use out of these two solutions ?

Comment: @RohitJindal any is better/worse - it depends of context. The second solution returns number (less space, faster processing) but you need to know global information about all items te generate next ID. The first solution returns string (slower/more space) but you need to know only local information about current project items to generate next ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one approach using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and the experimental [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). I will also append the product name to the new `identifier`:

```js
const productList = [{
  productGroup : 'PG1',
  index: 1,
  items: [
    {item1: 'item1 value', item2: 'item2 value'},
    {item1: 'item1 value', item2: 'item2 value'},
    {item1: 'item1 value', item2: 'item2 value'}
  ]
},
{
  productGroup : 'PG2',
  index: 2,
  items: [
    {item1: 'item1 value', item2: 'item2 value'},
    {item1: 'item1 value', item2: 'item2 value'}
  ]
}];

let newList = productList.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    let objs = curr.items.flatMap((x, idx) => Object.assign({
        productGroup: curr.productGroup,
        pgIndex: curr.index,
        itemIndex: [curr.productGroup, curr.index, idx].join("_")
    }, x));
    return res.concat(objs);
}, []);

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote below will get the job done for you and is an easy enough solution to visualise.
The solution required the use of nested for loops as we are also looping through the inner items array. I have added some comments to the code below to explain what is going on.

```
      const productList = [{
      productGroup : 'PG1',
      index: 1,
      items: [{
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value'
      },{
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value'
      },{
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value'
      }]
    }, {
      productGroup : 'PG2',
      index: 2,
      items: [{
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value'
      },{
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value'
      }]
    }];

    var count;
    for(var char in productList){
        count = 1; // Will reset to 1 when we go to a new product group
        for(var i = 0; i < productList[char].items.length; i++){
            // Adding in the unique key to the items.
            productList[char].items[i].uniqueKey = productList[char].productGroup + "_" + count;
            count++; 
        }   
    }
```

I hope this helps :P Let me know if you have any questions.